# LED solid ON ESP8266-01

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Is it possible to turn the build in LED solid "ON" on the ESP8266 ESP-01?
On the Arduino UNO REV.3 this code works, it sets the LED_BUILTIN to glow sold "ON":

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
}

void loop() {

}
```

On the ESP8266 ESP-01 this code works for blinking its built in LED:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   
  delay(1000);                     
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   
  delay(2000);                      
}
```

But I can not get it to be just solid "ON".

Comment: What happens when you try the first example on the ESP8266?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp nothing happens the LED is just "OFF".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Yes, it works the other way around. The LED will turn on with `digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);`.